# Have a discord bot send many messages with only one command

Tags: javascript, for-loop, bots, discord.io

I am making a cultist bot for discord, and I want it to send a message that repeats a message five times when an appropriate command is given **!praise**.

All the other commands run correctly (below I put one such command, **!saviour**, as an example), however, the **!praise** command never gives any output.

I was hoping it would iterate through the loop, sending a message each time, as you would expect from a `for` loop.

What stops the loop from running and how can I fix it?

```
bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
  if (message.substring(0, 1) === '!') {
    let args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    let cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
    switch (cmd) {
      case 'saviour':
        bot.sendMessage({
          to: channelID,
          message: 'Our current lord and saviour is named asghjahero'
        });
        break; //the above case works fine
      case 'praise':
        for (let i = 1; i === 5; i++) {
          bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: 'All Hail!'
          });
        }
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loop condition be `for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the condition in your `for` loop (`i === 5`). The loop will execute as long as that's true. But you start the loop off by assigning `i = 1`, and 1 is not equal to 5, even for large values of 1.

Comment: `i <= 5`... I knew I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, you just run `bot.sendMessage` twice in your listener.

Comment: It's bad practice, I'd prefer to use a loop imo to make the code look neater

Comment: I was meaning if you have to send entirely different messages but for your case you are right.